# Load qr code from url and display as image view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

As the title says I'm trying to take a qr code like this - http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=044779-A55W6UZD&chld=H|0 and display it as a UIImageview. I've searched but couldn't find an answer anywhere. Please help. 
I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work

```
    NSData *receivedData =  [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:receivedData];
UIImageView * myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 160, 200, 200);
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];
```

Comment: What doesn't work? In which method do you write this code?

Comment: The url wont load into NSData *recievedData. If i put a NSLog right after NSData *recievedData it says its null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try encoding the url like this and then use `encodedUrl` in the rest of the code:

```
NSString* encodedUrl = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

---

You should also remember to release the objects you created, otherwise you leak memory.

```
NSData* receivedData =  [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl]];
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:receivedData];
UIImageView* myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 160, image.size.width, image.size.height;
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];

[receivedData release];
[image release];
[myImageView release];
```